# MySQL stored procedure giving different results to command line

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, resultset

I have a simple MySQL stored procedure designed to return all child records for a given node.
My problem is when I type this manually it returns the proper results - but when I put the same code into a Stored Procedure it returns only the parent id.

I'd really appreciate some guidance!

For example - when I call my procedure (code is below) I get:

```
call find_child(1006);
+--------+
| nodeid |
+--------+
|   1006 |
|   1006 |
|   1006 |
|   1006 |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

BUT - When I cut and paste the command I get the proper resultset:

```
mysql> create temporary table KID_TABLE (nodeid INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert ignore into KID_TABLE (nodeid) select nodeid from CORPORATENODE 
       where parentid in (1006);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from KID_TABLE;
+--------+
| nodeid |
+--------+
|   1007 |
|   1008 |
|   1031 |
|   1038 |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `find_child`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `find_child`( IN NodeID INT)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare nid INT;
set nid= NodeID;
create temporary table KID_TABLE (nodeid INT);
insert ignore into KID_TABLE (nodeid) select nodeid 
from CORPORATENODE where parentid in (1006);
select * from KID_TABLE;
drop table KID_TABLE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here's the DDL for PARENT table

```
    CREATE TABLE  `PARENT` (  
    `NODEID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `PARENTID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 value means top node',  
    `NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`NODEID`) USING BTREE  
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Just a quick question, do you run this on windows? Your case looks messed up and that won't work good on a linux system with default configured mysql.

Comment: Your procedure is not DETERMINISTIC.  Try it without that (improper) specifier.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql will return your in variable NodeId in your `select nodeid 
from CORPORATENODE where parentid in (1006);`

Change the variable to in_NodeID instead.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `find_child`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `find_child`( IN in_NodeID INT)
BEGIN
create temporary table KID_TABLE (nodeid INT);
insert ignore into KID_TABLE (nodeid) select nodeid 
from CORPORATENODE where parentid in (in_NodeID);
select * from KID_TABLE;
drop table KID_TABLE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

But then of course, why use a temporary table?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `find_child`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `find_child`( IN in_NodeID INT)
BEGIN
select nodeid from CORPORATENODE where parentid in (in_NodeID);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Andreas et al,

I found a workaround to this just after posting - typical.
But couldn't post my solution till now.
I use Linux but have lower_case_table_names=1 set so the case is irrelevant. (I think?)

Andreas, I needed the temporary table as once I had selected back all the child records for a Node I then needed to update all the child records in the table NODEVERSION. I was running this via a trigger on the NODEVERSION table and was running into problems as I was updating the calling table etc. That's why I created a new CHILD_TABLE.

So I found that (even leaving DETERMINISTIC in... sorry pilcrow!)
The following worked as expected - all I did was added aliases ...
(The code below is a little different from above as I simplified the above code for my question)

Don't fully understand why the aliases fixed the initial problem - but it worked. Perhaps you experts know why?

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `find_child`( IN NodeID int)
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
     declare nid INT;
     declare rows_before INT DEFAULT 0;
     declare rows_after INT DEFAULT 0;
     set nid= NodeID;
     delete from CHILD_TABLE;
     insert into CHILD_TABLE values (nid);
     set rows_before = (select count(*) from CHILD_TABLE);
     if rows_before !=rows_after then
       increment: repeat
        set rows_before = (select count(*) from CHILD_TABLE);
        insert ignore into CHILD_TABLE (nodeid) select b.nodeid from CORPORATENODE b 
        where b.parentid in (select c.nodeid from CHILD_TABLE c);
        set rows_after= (select count(*) from CHILD_TABLE);
        until rows_before =rows_after
       end repeat increment;
    end if;
    update NODEVERSION n set STATUS=1 where n.nodeid in 
    (select c.nodeid from CHILD_TABLE c);
   END
```